# Concatenate generator and item

Tags: python, iterator, generator, list-comprehension

I have a generator (numbers) and a value (number). I would like to iterate over these as if they were one sequence:

```
i for i in tuple(my_generator) + (my_value,)
```

The problem is, as far as I undestand, this creates 3 tuples only to immediately discard them and also copies items in "my_generator" once.

Better approch would be:

```
def con(seq, item):
    for i in seq:
        yield seq
    yield item

i for i in con(my_generator, my_value)
```

But I was wondering whether it is possible to do it without that function definition

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) treats several sequences as a single sequence.

So you could use it as:

```
import itertools

def my_generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2

for i in itertools.chain(my_generator(), [5]):
    print i
```

which would output:

```
1
2
5
```

Comment: It's pretty crazy that addition of generators isn't builtin to python. I understand the finitude argument, but the same problem occurs for `itertools.chain`, right?

Answer (score 5):

[`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Answer (score 5):

Try `itertools.chain(*iterables)`.  Docs here: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain