# How to add extra key-value pairs to a dict() constructed with a generator argument?

Tags: python, syntax

One can create dictionaries using generators ([PEP-289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)):

```
dict((h,h*2) for h in range(5))
#{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8}
```

Is it syntactically possible to add some extra key-value pairs in the same dict() call? The following syntax is incorrect but better explains my question:

```
dict((h,h*2) for h in range(5), {'foo':'bar'})
#SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

In other words, is it possible to build the following in a single dict() call:

```
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 'foo': 'bar' }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Constructor:

```
dict(iterableOfKeyValuePairs, **dictOfKeyValuePairs)
```

Example:

```
>>> dict(((h,h*2) for h in range(5)), foo='foo', **{'bar':'bar'})
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

(Note that you will need to parenthesize generator expressions if not the sole argument.)

Answer (score 1):

```
dict([(h,h*2) for h in range(5)] + [(h,h2) for h,h2 in {'foo':'bar'}.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.chain` (see [Concatenate generator and item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443252/python-concatenate-generator-and-item)) to add your extra stuff into your call to `dict()`.

It's probably clearer to do it the easy way, though: one call to `dict` and then add the extra items in explicitly.