# Concatenate generators in python 3 with +-operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools

I was wondering why the `+` operator is not implemented for generators. Here [Concatenate generator and item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443252/python-concatenate-generator-and-item) the solution of itertools.chain is suggested, nevertheless I would think the `+` syntax is equally readable as it is for concatenating lists.

```py
gen1 = (x for x in [1,2,3])
gen2 = (x for x in [4,5,6])

# Works:
from itertools import chain
print(' '.join(map(str, chain(gen1, gen2))))

# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
print(' '.join(map(str, gen1 + gen2)))
```

Is there a (philosophical) reason why `+` is not available for generators? I think it would make code so much more readable that `interator.chain(...)`. Is there anything ambiguous about `gen1+gen2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current implementation of `__add__` for numbers, strings and sequences, the method returns a new object independent of the operands. ie.

```
x = [1]
y = [2]
z = x + y
x.append(1)
assert z == [1, 2] # z is not effected by the mutation of x
```

However, generators are both mutable (repeated calls to `next` do not necessarily return the same value), and more important *lazy*. That is, the generator object returned by the `__add__` is still intrinsically linked to the operands. eg.

```
x = iter(range(3))
y = iter(range(3, 6))
z = x + y
a = list(x)
b = list(z) # what should the contents of z be?
```

By the convention of the current semantics of `__add__` the contents should be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. However, because the generators are not independent the result will be `[3, 4, 5]`. Code example follows:

```
import itertools

class ExtendedGenerator:

    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = iter(gen)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.gen)

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return ExtendedGenerator(itertools.chain(self.gen, iter(other)))
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        try:
            return ExtendedGenerator(itertools.chain(iter(other), self.gen))
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented

x = ExtendedGenerator(range(3))
y = range(3, 6)
z = x + y
a = list(x)
b = list(z) # what should the contents of z be?

print("a:", a)
print("b:", b)
```

Which prints:

```
a: [0, 1, 2]
b: [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 7):

From the Python mailing list:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-April/006982.html

> > On Sun, Apr 4, 2010 at 9:58 AM, cool-RR  wrote:
> >
> > I'm still a bit confused by generators and generator expressions, but what
> >     about making a `generator.__add__` method, that'll act like
> >     `itertools.chain`?
>
> This gets proposed several times a year. We always shoot it down for
>   the same reasons: iterators are an abstract API and we don't want to
>   burden every iterator implementation with having to implement various
>   operations.
>
> -- 
>   --Guido van Rossum (python.org/~guido)

Comment: So in what case would this definition of `__add__` not work: `def __add___generators(x, y):\n\tfor xx in x: yield x\n\tfor yy in y: yield y` ?

Comment: It's not so much the fact that it wouldn't work (it appears that the idea has been suggested numerous times by people who think that it could), but that the Python BDFL would rather that this particular strain of iterator was kept free from overloading the `+` operator (like how there's no `__add__` method for dictionaries). It would introduce yet another possible meaning to the `+` operator for standard library objects.

Comment: For the dictionary, I can understand it because the `+` would not be not really act as a `+`, as it may 'dismiss' elements from the first operand, and I guess there is a similar reason for the generators, but I can't see it. Why is it there for lists but not for generators? Why would a generator implementer ever be burdened because a generator has an `__add__`-method, more than when the existence of `iterator.chain`? I'm not pleading for this feature, I just want to know why `generator.__add__` would mess up the python interface.

Comment: For example, when you noted: "It would introduce yet another possible meaning to the + operator for standard library objects". Would the idea be that if one reads `x+y` in some unfamiliar code, one only need to consider that x and y are integers, strings or lists, unless the coder explicitly defined an `__add__` somewhere else, making it more 'obvious' what the actual operation (integer addition or string/list concatenation) is?

Comment: Yes I think that's the developers' rationale behind rejecting it: Python is designed to be as simple and unambiguous as possible to read. Overloading operators (even with perfectly reasonable methods like this one) can harm that intelligibility.